# how to create Intents with Context from the DialogFlow API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to batch create a bunch of intents, and I want to assign an [Input context](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-input-output#input_contexts)

As far as I can see this should not need a session as it's just a string context name.
Like this in the GUI:
[image]

The API call I make creates the intent,
doesn't throw an error,
but I can't get the contexts to show up.

Is there some weird format to the `contexts` parameter?
I've exported the zip and looked at the JSON files, they're just an array of strings.

I've seen other code that seems to require a user conversation sessionId to create contexts. But the intents are global - not for a single conversation. And I assume these are just for tracking context within a single conversation session (or google astronaut engineering)

The data I'm POSTing looks like the below

There's a google example here that doesn't touch contexts
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/manage-intents#create_intent

I've tried contexts as various formats without success

```js
  // this is the part that doesn't work
  // const contexts = [{
  //   // name: `${sessionPath}/contexts/${name}`,
  //   // name: 'test context name'
  // }]

  const contexts = [
    'theater-critics'
  ]
```

```json
createIntentRequest {
  "parent": "projects/XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXX/agent",
  "intent": {
    "displayName": "test 4",
    "trainingPhrases": [
      {
        "type": "EXAMPLE",
        "parts": [
          {
            "text": "this is a test phrase"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "EXAMPLE",
        "parts": [
          {
            "text": "this is a another test phrase"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "messages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "this is a test response"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "contexts": [
      "theater-critics"
    ]
  }
}
Intent projects/asylum-287516/agent/intents/XXXXXXXX-e852-4c09-bda6-e524b8329db8 created
```

Full JS (TS) code below for anyone else

```js
import { DfConfig } from './DfConfig'
const dialogflow = require('@google-cloud/dialogflow');

const testData = {
  displayName: 'test 4',
  trainingPhrasesParts: [
    "this is a test phrase",
    "this is a another test phrase"
  ],
  messageTexts: [
    'this is a test response'
  ]
}
// const messageTexts = 'Message texts for the agent's response when the intent is detected, e.g. 'Your reservation has been confirmed';

const intentsClient = new dialogflow.IntentsClient();

export const DfCreateIntent = async () => {

  const agentPath = intentsClient.agentPath(DfConfig.projectId);

  const trainingPhrases = [];

  testData.trainingPhrasesParts.forEach(trainingPhrasesPart => {
    const part = {
      text: trainingPhrasesPart,
    };

    // Here we create a new training phrase for each provided part.
    const trainingPhrase = {
      type: 'EXAMPLE',
      parts: [part],
    };

    // @ts-ignore
    trainingPhrases.push(trainingPhrase);
  });

  const messageText = {
    text: testData.messageTexts,
  };

  const message = {
    text: messageText,
  };

  // this is the part that doesn't work
  // const contexts = [{
  //   // name: `${sessionPath}/contexts/${name}`,
  //   // name: 'test context name'
  // }]

  const contexts = [
    'theater-critics'
  ]

  const intent = {
    displayName: testData.displayName,
    trainingPhrases: trainingPhrases,
    messages: [message],
    contexts
  };

  const createIntentRequest = {
    parent: agentPath,
    intent: intent,
  };

  console.log('createIntentRequest', JSON.stringify(createIntentRequest, null, 2))

  // Create the intent
  const [response] = await intentsClient.createIntent(createIntentRequest);
  console.log(`Intent ${response.name} created`);
}

// createIntent();
```

Answer (score 1):

update figured out based on this
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.intents#Intent

```js
  const contextId = 'runner'
  const contextName = `projects/${DfConfig.projectId}/agent/sessions/-/contexts/${contextId}`
  const inputContextNames = [
    contextName
  ]

  const intent = {
    displayName: testData.displayName,
    trainingPhrases: trainingPhrases,
    messages: [message],
    inputContextNames
  };
```

Comment: Just to complete your answer, if you would like to add inputContextNames it should be a list of strings. However if you would like to add an outputContexts, it should be an object   (see the follow link https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.environments.users.sessions.contexts#Context)